# Logging in to Aruba's NBAPI for Mobility Master with requests failing

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, aruba

I am using `requests` to call to Aruba's NBAPI for mobility master. Their documentation is scarce with Python examples. The API requires an initial auth to get a UID which needs to be referenced in each GET request. I cannot get the login to work within Python.

I'm using a GET request which may be part of the issue but it's my understanding of the `curl` example provided by Aruba the default `GET` method is being used. Please note I'm also not verifying the SSL cert as my end goal is zero touch provisioning.

Here is the curl command they offer to auth

```
curl --insecure -c "aruba-cookie-jar" -d "username=username&password=password" https://<url-here>:4343/v1/api/login
```

command output:

```
{"_global_result": {"status":"0", "status_str": "You've logged in successfully.", "UIDARUBA":"<key output here>"}}
```

I tried to convert this into python using 'requests' as shown below

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False
r = session.get('https://<url-here>:4343/v1/api/login', auth=('username', 'password'))
```

I get the below when checking response (ipython)

```
In [6]: r.status_code
Out[6]: 401
In [7]: print(r.text)
{"_global_result": {"status":"1", "status_str": "Unauthorized request, authentication failed"}}
```

What am I doing wrong with this request? When using the POST method in Python results in the same output. I am thinking the `auth` method being used in my Python example is not correct.

Comment: Your question title makes it sound as if you think the SSL validation happened anyway. That you set SSL verification to `False` is really not the issue here.

Comment: Yeah i really screwed up the title.. my apologies, is there a way to edit it?

Comment: I was able to edit the post. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not making the same request. The `-d` switch for `curl` sends *POST* data, not an authorization header. From the `curl` documentation:

> `-d, --data <data>`
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

You are using a GET request, not POST. Send the username and password in the `data` argument, you can use a dictionary here to have `requests` handle encoding it to a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` formatted request body:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False
login_info = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'}
r = session.post('https://<url-here>:4343/v1/api/login', data=login_info)
```

In general, API documentation that uses `curl` command-line examples count on a minimal familiarity with that tool, it is always worth reading the [`curl` manpage](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) to understand what the switches do, as well as have a minimal understanding of HTTP headers and the likes.

When in doubt, use both `curl` and `requests` to send your request to the [httpbin.org test site](http://httpbin.org/), and compare the results. Here, using the [`/anything` endpoint](http://httpbin.org/#/Anything) with `curl` gives:

```sh
$ curl --insecure -c "aruba-cookie-jar" -d "username=username&password=password" https://httpbin.org/anything
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "password": "password",
    "username": "username"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Length": "35",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.54.0"
  },
  "json": null,
  "method": "POST",
  "origin": "...",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything"
}
```

while your `request` code outputs:

```
>>> import requests
>>> session.verify = False
>>> r = session.get('https://httpbin.org/anything', auth=('username', 'password'))
/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:842: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn((
>>> print(r.text)
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Authorization": "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.21.0"
  },
  "json": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "origin": "...",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything"
}
```

which should hopefully make it clearer what the differences where here.

Comment: Man I feel stupid... I DID read the man page for curl and missed the -d being a POST. Your answer did the trick and I truly appreciate the additional input about headers. I'll read up on it. Thanks again!